# Dllimport function that returns struct

Tags: struct, c++-cli, dllimport

I have a third-party .dll and i have to use its functions in C++/CLI code. I am trying to dllimport it but I recieve an error:

error C33385: 'msp_FormatMessage': a function that has a Dllimport custom attribite cannot return an instance of a class

In C# this problem can be solved by using StructLayout, but i can't find any way to solve this problem in C++/CLI.

Function definition:

```
[DllImport("drtl3.dll", EntryPoint = "msp_FormatMessage")]
extern "C++" msp_Message msp_FormatMessage(msp_Message* buffer, char type, char RT, char SA, char RTR_MC, unsigned short SAR_MCD, char dataWordCount, unsigned short data[], unsigned int bccw);
```

Struct definition:

```
typedef struct {
        msp_WORD type;  
        msp_WORD dataWordCount;
        msp_WORD bccw;   
        msp_WORD CmdWord1;
        msp_WORD CmdWord2;
        msp_WORD Data[32]; 
        msp_WORD StatusWord1;
        msp_WORD StatusWord2;
        msp_WORD loopback; 
        msp_WORD bsw;
        msp_WORD timetag;
        msp_BYTE present; 
        msp_BYTE transmit;
        msp_BYTE check;
        msp_BYTE role;
} msp_Message;
```

Comment: You should tag `C++/CLI` questions as such, many people that look around the `C++` tag don't even know it exists, so you should be explicit about it when asking

Comment: Are you sure that the result is returned directly and not as a pointer?

Comment: [The only `msp_FormatMessage` I could find](http://www.module.ru/upload/files/2604_rtl2gsw.pdf#page=47) does exactly that: `msp_Message* msp_FormatMessage(
msp_Message* buffer,
msp_BYTE type,
msp_BYTE RT,
msp_BYTE SA,
msp_BYTE RTR_MC,
msp_WORD SAR_MCD,
msp_BYTE dataWordCount,
msp_WORD *data,
msp_DWORD bccw);`

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare the structure it's returning as unmanaged, this will work fine:

```
#using <mscorlib.dll>
using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;

#pragma managed(push, off)
using msp_WORD = short;
using msp_BYTE = char;
typedef struct {
    msp_WORD type;
    msp_WORD dataWordCount;
    msp_WORD bccw;
    msp_WORD CmdWord1;
    msp_WORD CmdWord2;
    msp_WORD Data[32];
    msp_WORD StatusWord1;
    msp_WORD StatusWord2;
    msp_WORD loopback;
    msp_WORD bsw;
    msp_WORD timetag;
    msp_BYTE present;
    msp_BYTE transmit;
    msp_BYTE check;
    msp_BYTE role;
} msp_Message;
#pragma managed(pop)

[DllImport("drtl3.dll", EntryPoint = "msp_FormatMessage")]
extern "C++" msp_Message msp_FormatMessage(msp_Message* buffer, char type, char RT, char SA, char RTR_MC, unsigned short SAR_MCD, char dataWordCount, unsigned short data [], unsigned int bccw);
```

or if that doesn't work you can always just do it the C++ way that also works for C++/CLI somewhat

```
#include "windows.h"
#pragma managed(push, off)
using msp_WORD = short;
using msp_BYTE = char;
typedef struct {
    msp_WORD type;
    msp_WORD dataWordCount;
    msp_WORD bccw;
    msp_WORD CmdWord1;
    msp_WORD CmdWord2;
    msp_WORD Data[32];
    msp_WORD StatusWord1;
    msp_WORD StatusWord2;
    msp_WORD loopback;
    msp_WORD bsw;
    msp_WORD timetag;
    msp_BYTE present;
    msp_BYTE transmit;
    msp_BYTE check;
    msp_BYTE role;
} msp_Message;
#pragma managed(pop)

typedef msp_Message msp_FormatMessage_t(msp_Message* buffer, char type, char RT, char SA, char RTR_MC, unsigned short SAR_MCD, char dataWordCount, unsigned short data [], unsigned int bccw);

msp_FormatMessage_t *msp_FormatMessage;
HINSTANCE hDLL;

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    hDLL= LoadLibraryA("drtl3.dll");
    msp_FormatMessage = (msp_FormatMessage_t *)GetProcAddress(hDLL,"?msp_FormatMessage@@YA?AUmsp_Message_t@@PAU1@DDDDGDQAGI@Z");
    msp_Message test = msp_FormatMessage(nullptr, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, nullptr, 7);
    Console::Write("type ");
    Console::WriteLine(test.type);
    Console::Write("check");
    Console::WriteLine(test.check);

    //  std::cout << "type" << test.type << std::endl;
    //std::cout << "check" << test.check << std::endl;

    Console::WriteLine(L"Hello World");
    return 0;
}
```

The name `?msp_FormatMessage@@YA?AUmsp_Message_t@@PAU1@DDDDGDQAGI@Z` is what you can get by running `DUMPBIN /EXPORTS drtl3.dll` in the visual studio command line. Could also just be C linkage, which would make the name a lot smaller.

Comment: @maniac98066 well, I added the not so beautiful C++ way of doing it (that also works with CLI). I'm not CLI expert, so I can't really help you much with `DllImport`

Answer (score 0):

Don't understand the problem.. Show the code. Show the error message.. I just tested dllimport with structures..

You should note that dynamic loading via dlopen and dlsym or with loadlibrary and getprocaddress is usually preferred. Why? Because you cannot "always" dllimport. Example: dllexport with VS2012 does not always work with dllimport in g++. There's no defined standard for how symbols are exported.

Using Mingw-g++ 4.8.1

DLL:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <cstring>

typedef struct {
    unsigned short meh;
    unsigned short bleh;
    char we[50];
} foo;

extern __declspec(dllexport) foo some_func()
{
    foo f;
    f.meh = 10;
    f.bleh = 20;
    strcpy(f.we, "hello world\0");
    return f;
}

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HINSTANCE hinstDLL, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpvReserved)
{
    switch (fdwReason)
    {
        case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
            break;

        case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
            break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

Importer:

```
#include <iostream>

typedef struct {
    unsigned short meh;
    unsigned short bleh;
    char we[50];
} foo;

extern __declspec(dllimport) foo some_func();

int main()
{
    foo f = some_func();

    std::cout<<f.meh<<" "<<f.bleh<<" "<<f.we<<"\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Result:    `10 20 hello world`

Comment: Yeah, the questioner didn't sufficiently explain that he was actually using the `C++/CLI` specific `[DLLImport]` construct. But I guess your question is still relevant if he wants it to work in pure C++

Comment: Yes, you are right, I'm using C++/CLI. I've edited the question to make it clear.